# wanted to add two floating number which gets concatenated as string

Tags: javascript

i want to add two float number with fixed two decimal but its converted to string and get concatenated.I know its simple question but actually i'm in hurry

```
var a=parseFloat("15.24869").toFixed(2)
   var b=parseFloat("15.24869").toFixed(2)
```

Update when i enter input as

```
var a=parseFloat("7,191");
var b=parseFloat("359.55");
c=(a+b).toFixed(2)
O/P:NAN
```

why so?

Answer (score 3):

The `.toFixed()` method returns a string. Call it *after* you've performed the addition, not before.

```
var a=parseFloat("15.24869");
var b=parseFloat("15.24869");
var c=(a+b).toFixed(2);
```

After that, `c` will be a string too, so you'll want to be careful.

As to your updated additional question, the output is not `NaN`; it's `366.55`. The expression `parseFloat("7,191")` gives the value `7` because the `,` won't be recognized as part of the numeric value.

Comment: just to comment. In some cases, that´s not possible as the requirements for example, for tax calculation and the toFixed must be realized in each value before adding (weird tax rules around the world)

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz true, but doing tax calculations with binary floating point is fundamentally wrong anyway.

Comment: do you mind it´s better to use integers and work with implied decimals?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz there are various "big integer" and "big decimal" math packages that provide explicit control over rounding (etc) for financial calculation. It's much slower than JavaScript native numbers but at least you get the right answer :)

Comment: I´m now reading that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency and I´m completely agree with that. I´ve been working on a very big billing system (as product parametrization expert) and the system used was that... very clear and usefull..  thanks for the tip. I never minded which one was the main reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add parenthesys to parse float the whole result string

```
  var a=parseFloat((15.24869).toFixed(2));
  var b=parseFloat((15.24869).toFixed(2));
  c=a+b
```

Comment: This will generate runtime exceptions. There's no `.toFixed()` method on the String prototype.

Comment: sorry (the toFixed needs a number, not a string) sorry but I was writing fast

Answer (score 0):

doing c = a + b adds the two answers together. You might just want to turn them into a string then concatenate them.

```
var a=parseFloat("15.24869").toFixed(2)
var b=parseFloat("15.24869").toFixed(2)
var c = (a.toString() + b.toString());
```